# Make an anchor link to a section of a separate page in markdown

Tags: navigation, anchor, markdown

I'm making myself a personal wiki of sorts using markdown.
I want to go from the index page (foods.md) to a section of another page (fruit.md).

My problem is that the anchor link only takes me to the top of the Fruit page, not down into the Apples section.

Foods page:

```
* [Fruit](fruit.md)
* [Apples](fruit.md#apples)
```

Fruit.md:

```
#Fruit
...lots of text...
...more text...

# <a name="apples"></a>Apples
...info about apples...
```

Can I make anchor links to parts of other/different pages?

Comment: Using which Markdown processor?

Comment: I'm just doing my writing in Sublime Text 2 and using Google Chrome (+Markdown Preview extension).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it works for me, with [markdown extra](http://drf.grus.uberspace.de/fruit#apples).

But you can try the following Alternativ with a html-ID

```
<h1 id="apples">Apples</h1>
```

Or in  [markdown extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr)

```
# Apples {#apples}
```